# How to visualize TensorFlow Estimator weights?

Tags: debugging, machine-learning, tensorflow, visualization

How can I select a layer from a `tf.estimator.Estimator` and access the weights vector for each unit in that layer? Specifically, I'm trying to visualize a Dense layer's weights.

Looking at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py it seems that the *weights* are called *kernels*, but I'm not able to access those when using the Estimator abstraction.

Ps: for an example of an implementation of Estimator, let's reference https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/estimator

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Estimator [has a method](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py#L208) called `get_variable_value`. So, once you have produced a checkpoint (or loaded the variable values from one) and if you know the name of the dense layer, you could do something like this using [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

weights = estimator.get_variable_value('dense/kernel')
plt.imshow(weights, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Comment: how do you know the variable names? For example when using the LinearRegressor Estimator with FTRL optimiser, using the `get_variable_names()` method from the page you linked, I get `'global_step', 'linear/linear_model/X0/weights', 'linear/linear_model/X0/weights/part_0/Ftrl', 'linear/linear_model/X0/weights/part_0/Ftrl_1', 'linear/linear_model/X1/weights', 'linear/linear_model/X1/weights/part_0/Ftrl', 'linear/linear_model/X1/weights/part_0/Ftrl_1', 'linear/linear_model/X2/weights', 'linear/linear_model/X2/weights/part_0/Ftrl', 'linear/linear_model/X2/weights/part_0/Ftrl_1'` etc.

Comment: @ac2051 Can I modify these weights? I want a method like set_variable_value.

Comment: @natkinis Can I modify these weights? I want a method like set_variable_value

Answer (score 3):

I just used the pre-compiled [Estimator](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/samples/outreach/blogs/blog_estimators_dataset.py) for testing and this worked properly for me.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

names = classifier.get_variable_names()        
print("name:", names)
for i in names:
    print(classifier.get_variable_value(i)
```