# Getting the weights from TensorFlow's estimator.DNNClassifier

Tags: python, tensorflow

I understand that DNNClassifier is now trained via `estimator.DNNClassifier`. Before it was trained using `contrib.learn.DNNClassifier` so we could extract the weights using `get_variable_names()`. But there is no such method in the `estimator.DNNClassifier`. If `contrib.learn` is deprecated now, then how do we get the weights from the new `estimator.DNNClassifier`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, weights are called 'kernels' ([learnt from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45863744/how-to-visualize-tensorflow-estimator-weights))

For example, for:

```
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
   feature_columns=feature_columns, 
   hidden_units=[2])

estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn_train)
```

You can use `get_variable_value` like this:

```
print(estimator.get_variable_value("dnn/hiddenlayer_0/kernel"))
print(estimator.get_variable_value("dnn/hiddenlayer_0/bias"))
```